# Advanced SQLite query on many-to-many relationship

Tags: sqlite, many-to-many, boolean-logic

I'm wondering about the most efficient way to accomplish this, because I've encountered the problem in a few different manifestations in a surprisingly short time lately.

As a general example, let's say we have a blog with Post objects, Tag objects, and that they form a many-to-many relationship because, obviously, each post has many tags, which in turn can be associated with many posts.

Now for the actual problem: **how do I *optimally* query for all posts whose list of associated tags comply with a given condition?**

A fairly naïve solution of mine for the search ("contains asd but not fgh") looks more or less like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Post INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PostID FROM PostTags WHERE (
        PostID IN (SELECT PostID FROM PostTags WHERE TagID = 'asd')  
        AND 
        PostID NOT IN (SELECT PostID FROM PostTags WHERE TagID = 'fgh')
    ) 
) Results ON Post.ID = Result.PostID
```

The advantage is that I can generate this more or less arbitrarily for any logical expression I'm given (AST), the downside is that I have a nagging feeling that 'n' nested queries is hardly the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using subqueries is perfectly fine; they will be efficient if `Post.ID` and `PostTags.TagID` are indexed or primary keys.

However, you do not need so much nesting:

```
SELECT *
FROM Post
WHERE ID IN     (SELECT PostID FROM PostTags WHERE TagID = 'asd')
  AND ID NOT IN (SELECT PostID FROM PostTags WHERE TagID = 'fgh')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*
from posts
inner join posttags t1 on p.id = t1.post_id and t1.tagid = 'asd'
inner join posttags t2 on p.id = t2.post_id and t2.tagid in ('asd','xyz')
left join posttags t3 on p.id = t3.post_id and t3.tag_id = 'fgh'
where t3.post_id is null
```

Comment: That's a bit harder to expand in a way that can definitely handle all expressions you can throw at it, though. At least I don't see how to translate from "tag1 and (tag2 or tag3) and !tag4" into that.